# Trying to create JSON file and upload it to FTP Address

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm trying to build an Azure Function which triggers an endpoint which should create and later on upload a JSON file to a ftp address. I've tried some different approaches until now, but none of them seems to be working for me.
The following methods are called from the endpoint.

Here is my upload method:

```
        private void UploadFileToFtp(string jsonResult, WebClient client)
        {
            var fileName = "users.json";

            GetFile(jsonResult, fileName);

            var request = WebRequest.Create("path");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            byte[] fileContents;

            using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            }

            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            }
        }
```

And that's how i'm trying to write in a file, without saving it locally, taking into consideration that i have a serverless function.

```
        private void GetFile(string json, string fileName)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
            }
        }
```

Even though i'm not getting any error and everything seems to be working just fine, i just can't get the file on the FTP.
Any idea about what i'm doing wrong, is welcomed.

P.S: I've tried most of the solutions presented here, but for my case, for some reason, none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not see the log in your case, and not sure where you write the json file content. I just have a test with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json;
            json = "[\"aaaa\":\""  + "\"," +
                            "\"bbbb\":\""  + "\"," +
                            "\"cccc\":\""  + "\"," +
                            "\"dddd\":\""  + "\"," +
                            "\"eeee\":\""  + "\"," +
                            "\"ffff\":\""  + "\"," +
                            "\"gggg\":\""  + "\"]";
            WebClient _client= new WebClient();
            UploadFileToFtp(json, _client);
        }
        public static void GetFile(string json, string fileName)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
            }
        }
        public static void UploadFileToFtp(string jsonResult, WebClient client)
        {
            //you could set the file name with a random string
            var fileName = "myJson.json";

            GetFile(jsonResult, fileName);

             var request = WebRequest.Create($"ftp:your-ftp-url/site/wwwroot/{fileName}");
             request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
             request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "userpwd");

             byte[] fileContents;

             using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileName))
             {
                 fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
             }

             request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the file on server side:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I do generate a name for the file ( I have updated the question, as well ). I'm sorry for asking, but what log are we talking about? And also, it seems like it's working for you, so maybe, I'm not connecting to the right path or with the right credentials to the ftp.

Comment: I'm using the ftp endpoint and credential in Azure Web App Deployment Center, and notice the ftp url I post. About the log, I just want to see the details when you run your code, it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can have a try with my code, and would you mind accept my answer if it helps?

Comment: Yes, you were right, the ftp url i was trying to access was wrong and didn't match the right patter. Thanks a lot for your help!